# Extract specific words from a text file?

Tags: r, regex

I have a text file with over 10,000 lines, each line have a word that starts with the **CDID_** followed by 10 more characters with no spaces as below:

```
a <- c("Test CDID_1254WE_1023 Sky","CDID_1254XE01478 Blue","This File named as CDID_ZXASWE_1111")
```

I would like to extract the words that start with **CDID_** only to make the lines above look like this:

```
CDID_1254WE_1023
CDID_1254XE01478
CDID_ZXASWE_1111
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are three base R options.

**Option 1:** Use `sub()`, removing everything except the `CDID_*` section:

```
sub(".*(CDID_\\S+).*", "\\1", a)
# [1] "CDID_1254WE_1023" "CDID_1254XE01478" "CDID_ZXASWE_1111"
```

**Option 2:** Use `regexpr()`, extracting the `CDID_*` section:

```
regmatches(a, regexpr("CDID_\\S+", a))
# [1] "CDID_1254WE_1023" "CDID_1254XE01478" "CDID_ZXASWE_1111"
```

**Option 3:** For a data frame result, we can use the new `strcapture()` function (v3.4.0) and do all the work in a single call:

```
strcapture(".*(CDID_\\S+).*", a, data.frame(out = character()))
#                out
# 1 CDID_1254WE_1023
# 2 CDID_1254XE01478
# 3 CDID_ZXASWE_1111
```

Comment: Also `stringr::str_extract(string = a, pattern = "CDID_\\S+")`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a lookbehind with the **stringi** package:

```
a <- c("Test CDID_1254WE_1023 Sky","CDID_1254XE01478 Blue","This File named as CDID_ZXASWE_1111")

library(stringi)

stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(a, '(?<=(^|\\s))(CDID_[^ ]+)')
```

`(?<=(^|\\s))`  = preceded by the beginning of the line or space; then `CDID_` AND all then `[^ ]+` = characters that follow that are not spaces.

```
[[1]]
[1] "CDID_1254WE_1023"

[[2]]
[1] "CDID_1254XE01478"

[[3]]
[1] "CDID_ZXASWE_1111"
```

You may want to use `unlist` to force it into a vector.

Answer (score 1):

All the other solutions are great. Here is one solution using functions from `stringr` package. We can first split the string using `str_split` by space, convert the resulting list to a vector, and then use `str_subset` to get strings with `CDID_` in the beginning.

```
library(stringr)

str_subset(unlist(str_split(a, pattern = " ")), "^CDID_")
[1] "CDID_1254WE_1023" "CDID_1254XE01478" "CDID_ZXASWE_1111"
```