# Import multiple text file with first row's specific words

Tags: r, import, data.table, data-manipulation

I will use two files as example to explain my question.
I have multiple text files like below:

```
### First file
GEORGIA file name first row not use  
Col1  Col2  
A     2  
A     4   
A     5  
B     2  
B     6

### Second file  
New York file name first row not use  
Col1  Col2  
C     2  
C     4   
D     5  
E     2  
F     6
```

I use `data.table` to import text file and then extract information I want.

```
library(data.table)
my_read_data <- function(x){ data <- data.table::fread(x, header = T, strip.white = T, fill = T, skip = 1) }
file.list <- dir(path = "C:/Users/filesnames/", pattern='\\.txt', full.names = T)
dt.list <- sapply(file.list, my_read_data, simplify=FALSE)
cd <- rbindlist(dt.list, idcol = 'id')[, FileNo := substr(id, 24, 25)]
```

And the result is in the following:

```
Col1  Col2  FileNo
A     2     1
A     4     1   
A     5     1  
B     2     1  
B     6     1 
C     2     2  
C     4     2     
D     5     2    
E     2     2    
F     6     2
```

However, what I actually want is:

```
Col1  Col2  FileNo   Name
A     2     1        GEORGIA  
A     4     1        GEORGIA     
A     5     1        GEORGIA  
B     2     1        GEORGIA    
B     6     1        GEORGIA   
C     2     2        New York    
C     4     2        New York         
D     5     2        New York        
E     2     2        New York        
F     6     2        New York
```

Since I skip the first row, so I cannot extract the words from first row where I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991860/extract-specific-words-from-a-text-file).

But if I did not remove the first row, it imported incorrectly.

Text File shows like:

```
### First file
GEORGIA file name first row not use  
Col1,Col2  
A,2  
A,4   
A,5  
B,2  
B,6

### Second file  
New York file name first row not use  
Col1,Col2  
C,2  
C,4   
D,5  
E,2  
F,6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can read the first line separately and create a column

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(setNames(file.list, file.list), function(x) {
    dat <- fread(x, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE, fill = TRUE, skip = 1)
    v1 <- readLines(x, n = 1)
    dat[, Name := sub("\\s+file name.*", "", v1)]
    }), idcol = 'id')
```

Comment: Column `FileNo` is the specific text files name. For example,`FileName_01`, `FileName_02`. Extract 1 and 2.

Comment: Error in rbindlist(lapply(file.list, function(x) { : unused argument (.id = "id")

Comment: @PeterChen sorry, it is `idcol`. mix up with `bind_rows`

Comment: I think `[, FileNo := substr(id, 24, 25)]` are not identified the specific filenames

Comment: @PeterChen Removed that part

Comment: I need to add `simplify=FALSE` argument to make `[, FileNo := substr(id, 24, 25)]` works...

Comment: @PeterChen. But, that argument was added with `sapply` because sapply can coerce a list to matrix.  With `lapply`, it always returns a `list`

Comment: Solved. Just change `lapply` to `sapply` and add the argument.

Comment: @PeterChen. That is strange because `lapply` shouldd work in all the situations

Comment: @PeterChen May be, it is the names `lapply(setNames(file.list, file.list)` changed